# Execute NUnit test in Bamboo

Tags: c#, nunit, bamboo

How can I run NUnit tests in Bamboo?

In the NUnit Runner an executable is required to perform the task, but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a .net plugin for Bamboo.  https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugin/details/43168

And you can find more information on Atlassian Forums.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/10552/question-about-running-nunit-tests